# Is it possible to sort Azure DevOps board cards?

Tags: azure-devops

Sincerely apologize if this isn't the appropriate channel..

Currently utilizing Azure DevOps column boards to manage resources/employees. It's an odd tool choice, but I'm making it work.

**My question:**
Is there a way to sort board cards alphabetically, or would this be a manual process of dragging/dropping?

Answer (score 0):

Board cards order are defined in board settings. You can click the gear icon at top right to check the details(official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/reorder-cards?view=azure-devops#set-card-reordering-team-preference)).

[image]

1. If you select 1st option, you have to manually drag/move the cards to sort them alphabetically.
2. If you select 2nd option, the order are following backlog order, so you can drag backlog items and sort them alphabetically, the board card will be sorted alphabetically as well.

Both not supported sort automatically. As an alternative, you can create a query, filter the workitems(type, state...etc), they can be sorted alphabetically.

[image]

Comment: Greetings @Kyle, is there any update? if it makes sense to you, you can mark it as answer then it could help others as well. Thanks.